What creature is hanging from the roof in the Defence Against The Dark Arts class?
When you go to the Defence Against The Dark Arts class in Hogwarts Legacy, then there's a creature's bones (fossil) hanging from the roof:

It looks like some kind of dragon, possibly?
What creature is this?

That's a Hebridean Black skeleton belonged to Dinah Hecat, the Defence Against the Dark Arts Professor during the late 19th century:

This large dragon skeleton that hangs in the Defence Against the Dark Arts classroom is allegedly a trophy taken by Professor Hecat after she single-handedly defeated one of the largest poaching rings in Eastern Wales during the Great Poacher Raid of 1878.



The Hebridean Black was a dragon species native to the Hebrides islands of Scotland.


In HP world they call it "dragon", but technically that's a wyvern :)

To clarify, a wyvern is just a dragon with two hind legs. It supports itself on the front side by walking on the tips of its wings. Generally, wyverns are seen as inferior versions of dragons.
